# Filter results based on URL and simultaneously select option in dropdown box using angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, frontend

I am a beginner to Angular JS framework, I have made a client-company table and filtered clients by company name using drop down menu. But what if I want to filter results using URL like "#/client/company.name=A" and by clicking on that link only filtered results are shown- How can I filter results based on URL in Angular JS? I have dynamically generated the link but how can I filter results using the URL? Here is my  [Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/72h2gqk6/3/)

`

Total Filtered Client: {{filtered.length}}

```
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="btn-group" data-ng-class="{open: open}">
            <button class="btn">Filter by Company</button>
            <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-ng-click="open=!open"><span class="caret"></span>

            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                <li><a data-ng-click="checkAll()"><i class="icon-ok-sign"></i>  Check All</a>

                </li>


                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li data-ng-repeat="company in companyList"> <a data-ng-click="setSelectedClient()">{{company.name}}<span data-ng-class="isChecked(company.name)"></span></a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<hr/>
 <h3>Size Table:</h3>

<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th style="width:20%">Company</th>
            <th style="width:40%">Designation</th>
            <th style="width:30%">Name</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="client in filtered = (clients | companyFilter:selectedCompany)">

            <td><a href= "#!/clients/name= {{client.company.name}}">{{client.company.name}}</a></td>
            <td>{{client.designation}}</td>
            <td>{{client.name}}</td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

` 
my js code is:

```
         'use strict';
var App = angular.module('clientApp', ['ngResource', 'App.filters']);
App.controller('ClientCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.selectedCompany = [];
$scope.companyList = [{

    name: 'A'
}, {

    name: 'B'
}, {

    name: 'C'
}];

$scope.clients = [{
    name: 'Gray',

    designation: 'Manager',
    company: {

        name: 'A'
    }
}, {
    name: 'White',
    designation: 'M',
    company: {

        name: 'A'
    }
},{
    name: 'White',
    designation: 'M',
    company: {

        name: 'B'
    }
},{
    name: 'White',
    designation: 'Senior',
    company: {

        name: 'B'
    }
},{
    name: 'White',
    designation: 'Junior',
    company: {

        name: 'C'
    }
}, {
    name: 'White',
    designation: 'M',
    company: {

        name: 'A'
    }
},];

$scope.setSelectedClient = function () {
    var name = this.company.name;
    if (_.contains($scope.selectedCompany, name)) {
        $scope.selectedCompany = _.without($scope.selectedCompany, name);
    } else {
        $scope.selectedCompany.push(name);
    }
    return false;
};

$scope.isChecked = function (name) {
    if (_.contains($scope.selectedCompany, name)) {
        return 'icon-ok pull-right';
    }
    return false;
};

$scope.checkAll = function () {
    $scope.selectedCompany = _.pluck($scope.companyList, 'name');
};
```

}]);

```
angular.module('App.filters', []).filter('companyFilter', [function () {
return function (clients, selectedCompany) {
    if (!angular.isUndefined(clients) && !angular.isUndefined(selectedCompany) && selectedCompany.length > 0) {
        var tempClients = [];
        angular.forEach(selectedCompany, function (name) {
            angular.forEach(clients, function (client) {
                if (angular.equals(client.company.name, name)) {
                    tempClients.push(client);
                }
            });
        });
        return tempClients;
    } else {
        return clients;
    }
};
}]);
```

My query string is not #/client/company?name=A,B,C, my string will be "/clients/company.name=A"  to which the the table only shows results containing company A and the company A should be marked in the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$location` service. One possible solution is to add this in your controller:

```
$scope.location = $location;
$scope.$watch('location', function() {
    if($location.search().name)
    {
        $scope.selectedCompany = $location.search().name.split(',');
    }
});
```

Assuming your query string is: `#/client/company?name=A,B,C`

Comment: I tried adding this to the controller but didn't work.

Comment: My query string is: #/client/company.name= A

Comment: Still not working. The name tag will search the client, company.name will search the company name. I tried changing it but still it didn't work.

Comment: My query string is not #/client/company?name=A,B,C, my string will be "/clients/company.name=A"  to which the the table only shows results containing company A and the company A is marked in the dropdown menu.

Comment: A query string is everything that comes after the `?` in the url and needs to be a `&` separated list of `property=value`.

Comment: You may want to have a look at ui.router and how to pass parameters on your routes.

Comment: if I could add a filter when a url is clicked. When I use $location, the app doesn't render anything.

Comment: @GokuFrieza Try to consider my answer below. It will **help you** to **extract the parameter/s in your query string**. Also, I provided a working jsfiddle demo. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try to inject **ngRoute** as your dependency and use **$routeProvider** and **$routeParams** to extract/fetch the parameter/s in the URL.


You will be able to extract the url parameter/s by using **$routeParams**.


**E.g.**

 Your url path: **#/clients**. To set a parameter/s in your URL, just add **?company=A** to set the **$routeParams object/s**.


Your URL will be like **#/clients?company=A**, where **company** is the  **key** and **A** is the **value**.


You will be able to extract the url parameter/s by **$routeParams.company**.




**Here's the [Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/1sz8rhoq/8/)**.


**Sample codes:**


    'use strict';

```
var app = angular.module('clientApp', ['ngRoute', 'App.filters']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/clients', {
            templateUrl: '/this.html',
            controller: 'ClientCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/clients'});
});

app.controller('ClientCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    var companyName = $routeParams.company;
    console.log($routeParams);

    $scope.selectedCompany = [];
    $scope.companyList = [
        {name: 'A'},
        {name: 'B'},
        {name: 'C'}
    ];

    $scope.clients = [{
        name: 'Gray',
        designation: 'Manager',
        company: {name: 'A'}
    }, {
        name: 'White',
        designation: 'M',
        company: {name: 'A'}
    }, {
        name: 'White',
        designation: 'M',
        company: {name: 'B'}
    }, {
        name: 'White',
        designation: 'Senior',
        company: {name: 'B'}
    }, {
        name: 'White',
        designation: 'Junior',
        company: {name: 'C'}
    }, {
        name: 'White',
        designation: 'M',
        company: {name: 'A'}
    }];

    if (companyName) {
        if (_.contains($scope.selectedCompany, companyName)) {
            $scope.selectedCompany = _.without($scope.selectedCompany, companyName);
        } else {
            $scope.selectedCompany.push(companyName);
        }
    }

    $scope.setSelectedClient = function() {
        var name = this.company.name;
        if (_.contains($scope.selectedCompany, name)) {
            $scope.selectedCompany = _.without($scope.selectedCompany, name);
        } else {
            $scope.selectedCompany.push(name);
        }
        return false;
    };

    $scope.isChecked = function(name) {
        if (_.contains($scope.selectedCompany, name)) {
            return 'icon-ok pull-right';
        }
        return false;
    };
}]);
```

For **ngRoute** documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/

Comment: When I am using it on phone, it doesn't load JSON. It just company name {{company.name}} and other table values

Comment: Can I ask if the **Jsfiddle link** was the one you encountered the problem? If yes, I guest it is not working as expected in jsfiddle using phone. I think you try it not using jsfiddle. I'm sure it will work fine.

Comment: I think the problem is with Chrome developer tools, when I tried angular's tutorial( on Angular JS) website, it encountered same error as by Chrome developer tools .

Comment: **Jsfiddle** has different approach to run an application especially with **ANGULARJS**. You must try it not using **Jsfiddle**. Trying to run an **angularjs** app with jsfiddle needs different approach. I suggest try it not using jsfiddle.

Comment: ui.router is better than ngRoute and should be used instead this one. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: @JoaoLeal Yes, but the sample codes are not that complicated. It can be done by just using **ngRoute**. There's no need to complicate things.